# Adding Array of customized View in android and setting onClickListener mutually exclusive

Tags: android, arrays, view, onclicklistener

I am adding a Customized View using an array.The array elements are intialized by inflating a layout and adding those elements to a ViewGroup as shown in the image.
When I am setting onClickListener in a way to make the clicked view's background as Accent Color It happens but in order to **make it mutually exclusive** so that once a view is clicked other View's background should become transparent as they were intially I have used the following code But my when I click on the View, my applications stops responding.If my approach is not correct Please suggest me the right way to get desired result.

This should happen:

[image]

this should not happen:

[image]

```
if(noOfChild>1) {
        for (j = 0; j < noOfChild; j++) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            childButton[j] = (inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_selection_button, null));
            childButton[j].setId(j);
            children.addView(childButton[j], new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
            childButton[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainScreen.this, R.color.dimAccent));
                    //   for (int k =0;k<noOfChild;k++){
                    //       while(k!=v.getId()){
                    //           childButton[k].setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainScreen.this, R.color.transparent));
                    //       }
                    //   }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a local variable which shows the position of the last selected item. Then in your `onClick()` method do the switch in the position and the backgroundColor:

```
private View lastSelected;

//... rest of code ...

//Inside for loop
public void onClick(View v){
      if (lastSelected == null){
           lastSelected = v;
           selectItem(lastSelected);
      }
      else
      {
      deselectItem(lastSelected);
      lastSelected = v;
      selectItem(lastSelected);
      }
}

private void selectItem(View v){
     v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainScreen.this,R.color.dimAcent));
}

private void deselectItem(View v){
      v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainScreen.this, R.color.transparent));
}
```